# @PUT request not working in retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit2

I tried my request in both way. which is

```
@PUT("api/check-ticket/{reg_id}/{gate}/")
Observable<AppAllowTicketResponse> checkRealTimeTicketStatus(
        @Path("reg_id") String ticket_id,
        @Path("gate") int gate_id
);
```

And ..

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@PUT("api/check-ticket/{reg_id}/{gate}/")
Observable<AppAllowTicketResponse> checkRealTimeTicketStatus(
        @Field("reg_id") String ticket_id,
        @Field("gate") int gate_id
);
```

but its always ends by giving me error. HTTP 404 not found. I have other @GET and @POST request which is working. call is happening from here ..

```
mTicketCheckService.checkRealTimeTicketStatus(ticket_id, (gate_id+ValueConstants.GATE_ADD_VALUE))
            .subscribeOn(mNewThread)
            .observeOn(mMainThread)
            .subscribe(new Observer<AppAllowTicketResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("api error response: ", e.getLocalizedMessage());

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(AppAllowTicketResponse appAllowTicketResponse) {


                }
            });
```

I have no idea why this is happening. I have searched stackoverflow for similar problem but didn't get any solution.

Comment: Since other requests worked, I presume you have the internet permission turned on. Did you try the url in postman and see if it's good?

Comment: works fine i postman. URL is "http://base.url/api/check-ticket?reg_id=YB-40001&gate=16"

Comment: Did you try without the extra "/" at the end? "base.url/api/check-ticket?reg_id=YB-40001&gate=16" vs "base.url/api/check-ticket?reg_id=YB-40001&gate=16/"

Comment: found my problem. added as answer

Answer (score 1):

I did a silly mistake. It was all for wrong url format. the call is now

```
@PUT("api/check-ticket")
Observable<AppAllowTicketResponse> checkRealTimeTicketStatus(
        @Query("reg_id") String ticket_id,
        @Query("gate") int gate_id
);
```

and its perfectly working now.